# unable to fetch image from spring form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

while fetching file from `spring form` I am getting `null` value and If I try this code for rest of fields i mean *non* `multipart input types` its working fine. while debugging I am getting `null` value from line. If I try to fetch `image` from existing folder i'e image under webapp and that url is able to display image in browser but not able to read value from `files` using browser and sorry for my bad english

**edit** if i comment the image code, application is working fine but when I introduce the code for image I'm getting error

`MultipartFile file = domain.getImage(); //this is getting null`

this is relevent code
**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formInputGet(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("domain", new Domain());
        return "form";
    }



@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String formInputPost(@ModelAttribute("domain") Domain domain, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

            MultipartFile file = domain.getImage();
if (image== null)
            throw new NullPointerException("unable to fetch "+file); //getting NPE everytime
            String rootDirectory = httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            if (domain.getImage() != null && !domain.getImage().isEmpty())
                try {
                    File path = new File(rootDirectory + "images\\" + domain.getFirstName() + ".png");
                    file.transferTo(path);
                } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            repositiry.addToList(domain);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
```

**form.jsp**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="domain" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    First Name<br>
        <form:input path="firstName" />
        <br>Last Name :<br>
        <form:input path="lastName" />
        <br>upload Image<br>
        <form:input path="image" type="file" />
        <hr>
        <input type="submit">
    </form:form>
```

**dispatcherServlet**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <bean id="multipartReslover"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

I added some extra code to find if I am getting `domain` as `null` came to be true. And I have no Idea how to solve that.

after adding check for file i'm getting error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: unable to fetch : null
```

**domain.java**

```
public class Domain {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private MultipartFile image;

//getters and setters
```

**NOTE** any helpful answer if it have other way of working is welcomed too :)

any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Can you show your domain class

Comment: @kuhajeyan I made the edit

Comment: can you change to public String formInputPost(@ModelAttribute("domain") Domain domain,  BindingResult result) {...}
from 

public String formInputPost(@ModelAttribute("domain") Domain domain, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {..}

Comment: ok I'll try binding them all

Comment: @kuhajeyan I binded all results and then added to my `formdatapost(..)` controller but still It is passing to else part

Comment: Not sure, what exactly wrong there, may be you could try changing the type of file to CommonsMultipartFile

Comment: okey the main problem I am getting is I am able to pass names but if they are without `multipart file` they are getting displayed in `view` and after adding image , I am just getting only **static** content like `First Name nothing'sCommingHere'

Comment: And are you sure, you form has action set?

Comment: yes it is set to home page

Comment: form should point something like this, not your home page
<form:form modelAttribute="domain" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="xxxx/form">

Comment: its still not working

Comment: @kuhajeyan now I am redirecting to same page (i.e `form.jsp`) to dispaly but still not getting anything

Comment: have you added the  Apache Commons FileUpload and apache commons-io dependency

Comment: yes i have it....

Comment: are you using spring csrf?

Comment: lol noo..... I posted everything here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two typos in my configuration file as they are

1) `<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />` here mapping was supposed to be like `mapping ="images/**"`

2)`File path = new File(rootDirectory + "images\\" + domain.getFirstName() + ".png");` here path is supposed to be as `rootDirectory+"\\images\\"+....` instead

Answer (score 5):

you should do everything @kuhajeyen said and if getting image from domain object didnt go well you can try this

```
public String formInputPost(@ModelAttribute("domain") Domain domain,
                            @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile imagefile,
                            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest ) {

                            imagefile.transferTo(path);

                            }
```

edit :- change `method` attribute to `POST` inside the form otherwise it will make a `GET` request.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="domain" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and replace your input type file  with this line, i think there is some issues when trying to bind input type file  with an object.

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

Comment: yeah but `@requestParm(..)` will fetch `http` request and I am not even able to fetch values from form

Comment: you are missing  `method="post"` attribute inside the form, that's why you are not being able to fetch values from the request.

Comment: but when I am trying same method without `post` I am able to fetch the rest of parameters

Comment: and it fails when I add `multipart`

Comment: still getting null values

Comment: I made some edits, please check maybe they are helpfull

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the spring, how to resolve multipart file

add this bean

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="409600"/>
</bean>
```

And also  it seems you have not mapped your action in form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="domain" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="xxxx/form">
....

</form:form>
```

Comment: okey till I understand that action will redirect to some other servlet using mapping but here to where it is supposed to go?

Comment: @kuhejeyan I tried your method but can you tell me where to redirect that form?

Comment: @HelloWorld you can redirect to same page if you want to, but i guess you are looking the exact form url to post to, if so, that will be your action url for formInputPost method

Comment: @kuhaheyan the actual problem is I applied a `NPE` and its showing true please check my update on code

Comment: I applied `NPE` check right after method beginning, resulting true

Comment: why are you adding if (image== null)
            throw new NullPointerException("unable to fetch "+file); and what is 'image' here?

Comment: just to check weather I am getting image or not

Comment: and when i applied *else* to `if (image != null && !image.isEmpty()) ` turned out that it is not going in if block